# Setting up Jabber server for use with multiple AIM accounts?

Tags: home-server, instant-messaging, jabber, aim

I'm not sure if this belongs on Serverfault so I'll post here and it can get moved if people think it should. I have three AIM accounts I'd like to use on my Symbian phone, but all the IM apps I've found only support one account per protocol. I thought it may be possible to set up a Jabber Server and use an AIM transport to log onto multiple accounts. If this is possible I'd appreciate pointers to documentation and programs to do this. I'd rather use Linux to do this but can use windows if necessary. If there's an easier way to do this with out running my own server that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed a nice and easy to use [Jabber Server](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp), OpenFire.

You can install it on Windows without trouble.

OpenFire Installation instructions are easy to follow.

www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html

If a XMPP(Jabber) Server is the way to go to solve the problem, this server could be the way to go.

Good luck.

P.D. Hit the one link limit, it sucks.

Comment: +1 ... Jabber is awesome. Been looking for a jabberd GUI for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Jabber/XMPP is an open technology and you are not constrained to your own server and may use other servers services. So:

1. Register Jabber account on the server you like (unless you already have one)
2. Find three servers with AIM gateway
3. Register to each AIM gateway with different AIM account

Voila! You have three AIM accounts connected to your one Jabber account.